# Using encoding="utf-8" in Python 3.0 to encrypt text

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, utf-8

I have upgraded my version of python from 2 to three and a program I had used to encrypt text files does not work anymore. Below is a snippet of my code

```
for x in range(0, len(content)):
    output = chr(ord(content[x])+ord(key[x])%256)
    crypt = crypt + output

new.write(crypt)
```

I understand that python does not use ASCII anymore but the new system seems a bit complicated and difficult to work with for my purpose. Is there any way I can use encoding="utf-8" to make my program work without overcomplicating or changing my code too much? I would appreciate all answers. Below is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Desktop\programing\Python Files\Encryptor and Decryptor\encryption.py", line 26, in <module>
new.write(crypt)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x93' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Why does your "encryption algorithm" operate on textual data in the first place?  You should be performing these operations at a binary level rather than above character encodings.  If you do that, you won't have this issue.

Comment: You need to use `bytes` objects (raw or encoded data) instead of `str` now.